# Laravel convert date format

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to convert something like "2020-01-01 00:00:00" into "Wed, Jan 1, 2020". Is there a way to do this in laravel?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/convert-datetime-to-readable-date

Comment: Laravel makes use of the Carbon library, which extends DateTime, and if this value is coming from something like a `created_at` or `updated_at` field on a model it is already a Carbon object

Comment: I see, I also checked the link and saw something useful there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
date('D, M j,Y', strtotime($user->created_at));
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses Carbon library out of the box, so you can get what you want just using it:

`{{ $user->created_at->toDayDateTimeString() }}`